# C - ZLib - Invert Compression

Tags: c, zlib, compression

I've just installed ZLib on Visual Studio 2015.

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <Perso.h>

#include "zlib.h"

int main()
{
    size_t fileLength = fileSize("Input.txt", 0);



    unsigned char* a = NULL;
    a = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*fileLength);
    verifyMalloc(a);
    nullString(a, fileLength);
    fileInUnsignedCharTab("Input.txt", a, fileLength, 0, 0, 0);

    unsigned char* b = NULL;
    b = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*fileLength);
    verifyMalloc(b);
    nullString(b, fileLength);

    unsigned char* c = NULL;
    c = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*fileLength);
    verifyMalloc(c);
    nullString(c, fileLength);



    uLong ucompSize = fileLength + 1;
    uLong compSize = compressBound(ucompSize);

    compress((Bytef *)b, &compSize, (Bytef *)a, ucompSize);
    uncompress((Bytef *)c, &ucompSize, (Bytef *)b, compSize);

    FILE* Output = NULL;
    Output = fopen("Output.txt", "wb+");
    fwrite(b, sizeof(b[0]), strlen(b), Output);
    fclose(Output);
}
```

compresses the file Input.txt and puts the result into Output.txt.
Now, imagine I send the compressed file, Output.txt, to a friend, how will he decompress the file ?

I tried the same code but only with

`uncompress((Bytef *)c, &ucompSize, (Bytef *)b, compSize);`
but it gives me a weird result, unreadable...

If you have an idea to decompress the compressed Output, it would be great :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: In "output.txt", you should not write `strlen(b)` bytes, but `compSize`. Indeed, the compressed stream could have some `nul` bytes in it, which would make `strlen(b)` lesser the `compSize`.

Comment: Moreover, why do you set `ucompSize = fileLength + 1`? (why the `+1`?). And you should test for the return of `compress` and `uncompress` functions.

Comment: Thank for your answer, no more problems :)
It was because of the strlen(b), this is good with compSize.
+ 1 is for the terminator '\0'